# For loop to parse xml to table

Tags: php, xml, for-loop, foreach

The following is part of an XML Response that I parse using simpleXML. I need to create a table like the example below, but i'm quite unsure of how to achieve that.

```
$roomCategory ='
<ChargeConditions>
 <ChargeCondition Type="cancellation">
  <Condition Charge="true" ChargeAmount="2730.00" Currency="USD" FromDay="0" ToDay="0"/>
  <Condition Charge="true" ChargeAmount="390.00" Currency="USD" FromDay="1" ToDay="2"/>
  <Condition Charge="false" FromDay="3"/>
 </ChargeCondition>
 <ChargeCondition Type="amendment">
  <Condition Charge="false" FromDay="0"/>
 </ChargeCondition>
</ChargeConditions>';
```

Desired Table

```
 __________________________________________________
|____________|_____Cancelation____|___Ammendment___|
|  FromDay 0 |      2730.00       |   No Charge    |
|  ToDay 0   |                    |                |
|____________|____________________|________________|
|  FromDay 1 |       390.00       |   No Charge    |
|  ToDay 2   |                    |                |
|____________|____________________|________________|
|  FromDay 3 |      No Charge     |   No Charge    |
|            |                    |                |
|____________|____________________|________________|
```

I am having a trouble since the ammendment condition comes in a different node, I am trying to do something like this, but I'm not sure if I am on the right track, and how to echo everything to form the table above.

UPDATED CODE:

```
$chargeConditions = $roomCategory->ChargeConditions;
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th></th>';
foreach ($chargeConditions->ChargeCondition as $condition) {
  echo '<th>' . ucfirst($condition['Type']) . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
$val = array();
$c = 0;
foreach ($chargeConditions->ChargeCondition as $condition) {
  $val[$c][0] = $condition["Type"];
  $charges = $condition->Condition;
  var_dump($charges);
  foreach($charges as $charge){
    if($charge["Charge"] !== "false"){
   $val[$c][1] = $charge["FromDay"];
   $val[$c][2] = $charge["ToDay"];
   $val[$c][3] = $charge["ChargeAmount"];
     }
  }
   $c++;
 }

for($x=0; $x <= $c; $x++){
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>From Day' . $val[$x][1] .'<br>To Day' . $val[$x][2] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $val[$x][3] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $val[$x+1][3] . '</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

The code above produces a table similar to this one:

```
 __________________________________________________
|____________|_____Cancelation____|___Ammendment___|
|  FromDay 3 |                    |                |
|  ToDay     |                    |                |
|____________|____________________|________________|
|  FromDay 0 |                    |                |
|  ToDay     |                    |                |
|____________|____________________|________________|
|  FromDay   |                    |                |
|  ToDay     |                    |                |
|____________|____________________|________________|
```

var_dump($charges) gives the following output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#455 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(5) { ["Charge"]=> string(4) "true" ["ChargeAmount"]=> string(7) "2730.00" ["Currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["FromDay"]=> string(1) "0" ["ToDay"]=> string(1) "0" } } object(SimpleXMLElement)#504 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["Charge"]=> string(5) "false" ["FromDay"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

Comment: You're sure that works? $condition['type'] and $condition->Condition together??? You either have an array or an object.

Comment: @DavidSarmiento $condition["Type"] will output "Cancelation" and $condition->Condition is an array of the 3 `condition` nodes under the `ChargeCondition` node.

Answer (score 0):

I would have everything parsed into an array whose keys are FromDay... something like

```
$cancellation=array();
$amendment=array();
foreach ($chargeConditions->ChargeCondition as $condition) {
$var = $condition->attributes()->Type;   
    foreach($condition as $child)
    {
         $$var[$child->attributes()->FromDay]=($child->attributes()->Charge)?$child->attributes()->ChargeAmount:"No Charge";
    }

}
```

Once the arrays are in place just do another loop.

```
<table><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Cancel</td><td>Ammend</td></tr>
<?php
foreach ($cancellations as $fromDay=>$cancel)
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $fromDay?></td>
<td><?php echo $cancel?></td>
<td><?php echo isset($ammendment[$fromDay])?$ammendment[$fromDay]:"No Charge"?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: I used your code but the table echoes only with the headers "cancelation" and "amendment", I updated my code to the current that I have, I can't figure it out yet.

Comment: make sure you use SimpleXMLElement objects, not your custom defined class